# Why the jQuery snippet works without the IFrame, but does not with an IFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Works

```js
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
  alert(1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

Does not work

```js
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
  alert(1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
<iframe id="myIframe" src="" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" />
```

Comment: Because your markup is invalid. An `iframe` is not a void element.

Comment: Indeed - swap `/>` for `></iframe>` and you'll see it works.  [MDN - iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe): _Tag omission None, both the starting and ending tag are mandatory._

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the MDN reference.

Comment: Is this question relevant to keep it around? I'll delete it if not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your markup is invalid. [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) is not a void element. You should close the `iframe` properly.

The first rendered HTML in my Chrome browser:

```
<html><head>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("a").on("click", function(e) {
  alert(1);
});
    </script>

</body></html>
```

The second one:

```
<html><head>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
<iframe id="myIframe" src="" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
    &lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;
        $("a").on("click", function(e) {
  alert(1);
});
    &lt;/script&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;</iframe></body></html>
```